# Troubleshoot keyboard shortcut: "View split on right"

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys

Is there a way for me to troubleshoot a keyboard shortcut which I think should be in effect but isn't?

After switching from Unity to Gnome in Ubuntu 20.04, my keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> does nothing, even though <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> successfully moves the selected window against the left side of the monitor and resizes it so that it occupies the entire left of the screen. (I'd like for <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to move+resize the active window against the rights side of the screen.)

**Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts** shows no disparity between the two:

[image]

And I've reviewed my **Settings > Custom Shortcuts** as well, but I've found no item with that key combination.

I've also looked at **CompizConfig Settings Manager > Window Management > Grid** and found no explanation. (Incidentally, the "Left Maximize" and "Right Maximize" shortcuts specified in CompizConfig appear to have no effect.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I troubleshot this by checking all keybindings in gsettings and grepping the output for the binding that I sought (`'<Super>Right'`):

```bsh
gsettings list-schemas | grep keybinding | while read SCHEMA; do
  gsettings list-keys $SCHEMA | while read KEY; do
    echo -ne "$KEY\t$SCHEMA\t"
    gsettings get $SCHEMA $KEY
  done
done | grep '<Super>Right'
```

...for me, this resulted in 4 different entries for the `'<Super>Right'` binding. Then I set them all to `['disabled']`:

```bsh
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-side-e "['disabled']"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm push-tile-right "['disabled']"
gsettings set org.gnome.metacity.keybindings toggle-tiled-right "['disabled']"
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-right "['disabled']"
```

...Then I used **Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts** to re-enable the one labelled **View split on right**.